# How can I open a *.gt file?

Tags: files, extension

Hi guys I was trying to open some files that the teacher sent as tests but they are in an extension that I can't find a way to open, *.gt. They are to be used inside a .py file for the test. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: i think you can open it with a simple text editor, try that

Comment: Text editor did not work, but gedit did.

Comment: gedit *is* one of the many text editors running under Ubuntu...  Also your question is a bit off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open it with gedit. When it is a binary file you should ask your teacher. When not you should see the content, more or less helpful.

Comment: i found out that a command used in some IDE software, for build-and-run button, that uses a .gt file for tracking source code changes and only recompile affected dependencies! so it may be it.